# Is iinc atomic in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, atomic

I know increment operation is not atomic in C++ without locking.

Will JVM add any lock on its implementation of `iinc` instruction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No its not

- Retrieve the current value of c.
- Increment the retrieved value by 1.
- Store the incremented value back in c.

[Java Documentation for Atomicity and Thread Interference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html)

You need to either use `synchronized` keyword or use `AtomicXXX` methods for Thread safety.

**UPDATE**:

```
public synchronized void increment() {
    c++;
}
```

or

```
AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(1);
//somewhere else in code
integer.incrementAndGet();
```

Also read: [Is iinc atomic in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287419/is-iinc-atomic-in-java/30269266#30269266)

Comment: you should read the concurrency documentation of Java which is quite nice for understanding the basic concepts of Java Concurrency.

Comment: +1 for good references. To be pedantic, I believe `integer.getAndIncrement()` is the equivalent of `i++` (not `incrementAndGet()`)!

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `i++` compiled to `iinc` for local variables, where concurrency is **not** a concern. If `i` is a field, then it's compiled as @Ellen Spertus's answer, where proper synchronization is needed. Related to this topic, this question has a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic

Comment: @EfeKahraman so does this mean that the Java bytecode instruction `iinc` is thread-safe or not?

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer: [`iirc` is only applicable to local variables, thus thread safety is irrelevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269266/3424423)

Answer (score 14):

The answer to your question depends on whether you mean the `IINC` instruction or, what other answers are referring to, the `++` operator.

Using `++` on a static or instance field is nothing more than get, increment, and set, thus it is not atomic (the other answers explain this in more detail).

But since you asked if the `IINC` *instruction* is atomic, this is not the real answer. In fact, none of the answers to this question address the instruction, all of them seem to be based around the operator being used on instance or static fields.

The `IINC` instruction only operates on local variables. As the name suggests, they are local and only accessible from a very limited scope. Thus, it is not possible to access a local variable from another Thread. This means that it doesn't matter whether or not the instruction is atomic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Nicely clarified! Added link to your answer from my answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Not it's not and it can cause real problems. This test is supposed to print 200000000 but it doesnt due to thread interference

```
static int n;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                n++;
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Note that `volatile` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, this code does not even use the `IINC` instruction to increment the `n` field. `IINC` is only used for local variables, and in this case only for `i++`.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not atomic, the bytecode can get interleaved with other threads.

Answer (score 0):

i++ is not atomic in java.
It is better to use

```
AtomicInteger atomic= new AtomicInteger(1);
```

There are methods defined like

```
atomic.getAndDecrement();
atomic.getAndIncrement();
atomic.decrementAndGet();
atomic.incrementAndGet();
```

any operation with above method would be atomic.

This class comes under `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package.
Java `1.5` has added many features for thready safety and thread concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

It is not atomic.  Here is the generated byte code for an post-increment of a static int:

```
0 getstatic 18;    // Load value of variable.
3 iconst_1;
4 iadd;
5 putstatic 18;    // Store value.
```